# How do I sign my Android apk for Google Play submission

Tags: android, google-play

I am just following the instruction by Google [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html), and I am failing in step 3:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

I get this message:

```
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: myApp.  myApp must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Btw, I'm not using Eclipse and Android Studio. The apk is already been built in release mode and the project were not done in Eclipse/Android Studio, so I figured I would have to use jarsigner.

Comment: I think this example will helpfull.  http://pulse7.net/android/digitally-signing-android-applications/

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I'm not using Windows though :( And this should be possible with jarsigner.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Did you create your own keystore like `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Comment: @TGMCians Yup, I did that. I followed the steps in the Google docs.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Try to create a new keystore file then try it. It should work, let me know if this work for you

Comment: @TGMCians nayoso helped me, it turns out I gave in a wrong alias name. Error message should be more helpful than that ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You give wrong parameter at the alias_name parameter
the basic format of jarsigner is

> $ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
>   my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name

So you should change your alias_name with correct one :) 
you can check it with

keytool -keystore yourkeystorename.keystore -list -v

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android studio go to Build->Generate sign apk
if you use Eclipse right click on the project Android tools-> export signed apk

Comment: Lucian: I'm not using Eclipse or Android Studio though, I just have the built APK and keystore.

Comment: for keystore click on create new...complete the informations there after this will be provided a keystore file. put the keystore path and  don't forget to remember the keystore pass and key pass. complete the informations on the first screen and click next...A sign apk will be provided

Answer (score 0):

If you are on eclipse, go to your manifest and click

```
Use the export wizard to export and sign apk
```

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse or Android Studio though, I just have the built APK and keystore.

Comment: Well you haven't specified that, anyway you can try Lucian Novac answer